# git lfs migrate and tracking issue

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I am trying to use git lfs to push my changes into git. Here is my current folder structure.

```
C:.
└───src
    ├───data
    │   ├───cifar-10-batches-py
    │   └───MNIST
    │       └───raw
    └───__pycache__
```

When I push my changes from `\src`, I get this error

```
$ git push origin
Uploading LFS objects: 100% (1/1), 170 MB | 0 B/s, done.
Enumerating objects: 130, done.
Counting objects: 100% (130/130), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (120/120), done.
Writing objects: 100% (124/124), 325.03 MiB | 11.48 MiB/s, done.
Total 124 (delta 58), reused 1 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (58/58), completed with 4 local objects.
remote: error: Trace: 9bbd1fa3bc86bd1c099238831cfa07a44dbeb01bcb3907a66d0fcd8a5cf5b538
remote: error: See https://gh.io/lfs for more information.
remote: error: File src/data/cifar-10-python.tar.gz is 162.60 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To https://github.com/manish-cr/CNN.git
 ! [remote rejected] manish/dev -> manish/dev (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/manish-cr/CNN.git'
```

So, I have used the below 2 methods

```
git lfs track "data/*.gz"
git add .gitattributes
git commit -m "pushing changes"
git push origin
```

```
git lfs migrate import --incldue="data/*.gz"
git add .gitattributes
git commit -m "pushing changes"
git push origin
```

both of these gives the same result. Any help on this is appreciated. Thanks.